# Define limits for varchar characters in SELECT statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

A bit of an odd question.  I am querying a DB where articles kept.  All articles have a season tied to them and thus they can appear more than once in the DB for various seasons.  When I SELECT the article & the MAX season, I am not getting the correct result leading me to believe that the logic was not put in place to define which seasons are most recent etc (I have read only access to this DB).  For example when selecting an article and MAX season, I get the result that the max season is SS2016 when in reality checking the source system, the max season is FW16 (spring/summer, fall/winter).  However if I use the MIN function, the season shows as FW16 which is correct for max, but F is before S in the alphabet leading me to believe there is no datetime logic involved...  Is there any way in a SELECT statement, to tell the query that SS is always less than FW.  It is always either SS or FF followed by a four digit year, i.e FW2016 & S2016.

Query is below:

```
SELECT ARTICLE_NUMBER,
       MAX(SEASON)

FROM   vw_GIM_Articles

WHERE  ARTICLE_NUMBER = 'Q10176'

GROUP BY ARTICLE_NUMBER;

SELECT ARTICLE_NUMBER,
       MIN(SEASON)

FROM   vw_GIM_Articles

WHERE  ARTICLE_NUMBER = 'Q10176'

GROUP BY ARTICLE_NUMBER;
```

**Results are (in order above queries):**

```
ARTICLE_NUMBER     
------------------ -------
Q10176             SS2016

(1 row(s) affected)

ARTICLE_NUMBER     
------------------ -------
Q10176             FW2016

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e5c8/20)

```
SELECT TOP 1 ARTICLE_NUMBER,Season, SUBSTRING( SEASON,3,50)
FROM   vw_GIM_Articles
WHERE  ARTICLE_NUMBER = 'Q10176'
ORDER BY CONVERT( int, SUBSTRING( SEASON,3,50)) DESC ,
    cast(CASE WHEN Season LIKE 'FW%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit)  desc
```

If you would like to select list of articles

try this,[[SQL Fiddel Demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15dee/10/0)

```
;WITH grouped AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ARTICLE_NUMBER 
                            ORDER BY CONVERT( int, SUBSTRING( SEASON,3,50)) DESC ,
                            cast(CASE WHEN Season LIKE 'FW%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit)  desc ) AS rn
   FROM vw_GIM_Articles
)
SELECT *
FROM grouped
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: just a follow up question, as you can tell I am not familiar with "bit", how does that assist in this?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user3496218 you can use int instead of bit .

Comment: In the case that I have several articles, what would be the best way to write this statement.  So instead of equaling one article #, I have a list of 1500 or so, rendering TOP 1 kind of useless.  When I take it off though I get several instances of each article.